# How can i give gradient to text in react-native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I tried

> import { LinearTextGradient } from "react-native-text-gradient";

but this is not work for text gradient. It gives error. it says *"No ViewManager defined for class RNLinearTextGradient"*

i need to give gradient to text  for ios and android